# Is there a display technology that unites red, green and blue subpixels into a single pixel?

Tags: display

After checking out [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42306/why-do-two-perfectly-adjacent-rectangles-create-black-or-white-lines-in-between) about a visual side effect caused by separation of each pixel into subpixels (red, green and blue), I thought that there might be a way to unite the subpixels into whole pixels using square matte filters. Various displays are built in a way that makes the formations of subpixels non-square, or even different size of subpixels, and subsequently their count, so I'm not sure if it could work with those (unless they'd have some odd shape). Is there any such thing on the market?

Comment: Technically single chip DLP's have a color wheel (rotating at crazy speeds) to produce color via image retention of the eye. The result are single pixels of any color, the color mixing occurs by the amount each pixel is on during each color cycle.

Comment: A very old cathode ray tube technology, usually only supporting 2 colours : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penetron

Comment: Seems like it should be possible to do this with LCD screens that have LED backlights - instead of using white LEDs and color filters in the pixels, what about flashing different backlight colors and using monochrome pixels, like a DLP projector?  This would easily give you a 3x pixel density increase as well.  Not sure why this isn't used.  Perhaps getting the correct synchronization is tricky, or perhaps color calibration, especially as the display ages.

Answer (score 2):

It would be possible to design a display with diffusing elements, each of which could receive illumination from three light sources.  It would be difficult, however, to have a diffusing element which would not send any light back toward its origin (wasting brightness), nor reflect any light that came from outside back toward the outside (creating an inferior "black level" or causing glare).  Additionally, is generally both easier and more effective to design all lights to have parallel light-vs-angle distributions than to try to aim each light toward the center of its pixel.  If lights are aimed toward the centers of their pixels, it will be necessary to either design the diffusers to counteract that effect or else tolerate significant color shifts with viewing angle.

For all of those reasons, even if it would be conceptually "nicer" for a 640x480 display to contain a 640x480 grid of three-color pixels than to have a 1920x480 grid where each pixel is red, green, or blue, the latter design offers substantial advantages which outweigh the fact that physical pixels don't quite match the logical definition.

Answer (score 2):

[Scanned Laser (Pico) Projectors](http://www.microvision.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/OPN_Article.pdf) are such a technology. Three monochrome beams of laser light are combined on a single axis, prior to being mechanically scanned via one or more mirrors.